# In bash, can I asynchronously open sockets and use them later?

Tags: bash, networking, socket

I had no idea that Bash supported so many advanced features!  I started working on a simple network program to try and use some of these things I found.  My particular program is a basic redis client written completely in Bash.  Currently, I can do something like the following:

```
redis_command -c "ping" redis{001..100}:{6379..6400}
```

It will send the "ping" command to all of the instances (about 2100) and return the results.  I'm currently sending the "ping" command serially, but I thought I could speed up my program by doing all of the initial socket creation in parallel.  I tested my program with/without the optimization, and realized that my optimization actually slowed things down.  Here's how the optimization looks:

```
declare -A SOCKETS
function get_socket {
  # args: <hostname> <port>
  # returns: the socket number, or failure return code

  # verify args
  if [[ -z "${1}" ]]; then
    return 1
  fi
  if [[ -z "${2}" ]]; then
    return 1
  fi

  local HOSTPORT="${1}:${2}"
  if [[ -z ${SOCKETS[${HOSTPORT}]} ]]; then
    exec {fd}<>/dev/tcp/${1}/${2}
    SOCKETS[${HOSTPORT}]=${fd}
    RES=${fd}
  else
    RES="${SOCKETS[${HOSTPORT}]}"
  fi
}

if [[ ${PRECONNECT} -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo -n "Pre-connecting to ${#HOSTS[@]} instances... " >&2
  for HOST in ${HOSTS[@]}; do
    get_socket "${HOST%%:*}" "${HOST##*:}" &
    PIDS+=($!)
  done

  # make sure all of our async connections finished before starting
  # TODO, check for errors
  for PID in ${PIDS[@]}; do
    wait ${PID}
  done
  echo "done" >&2
fi
```

Normally, the get_socket() function on its own works great.  If I ever need to send a command to a particular server, I call get_socket() ahead of time, and pass the FD to another function that actually sends the command and parses the response.  In the pre-connect scenario, I'm calling get_socket in the background via &.  Since get_socket()& runs in a separate process, the FD created isn't available/accessible in the calling process, so my optimization is useless.

Is there any way to send sockets in bash, or some other way that I can parallelize my connects without using a separate process?

Answer (score 3):

Not with `/dev/tcp/x/y` directly, but you could use pipes to communicate with processes that are started in the background to connect the TCP sockets and transfer data.

Something like

```
coproc hostA {
  exec {fd}<> /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/80
  cat <&$fd & cat >&$fd
}

# same for hostB...

echo -e 'HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r' >&${hostA[1]}
cat <&${hostA[0]}
```

As you end up running two `cat` commands anyway, you might as well do without `/dev/tcp` (which is not always enabled) and use for instance socat:

```
coproc hostA { socat - tcp:localhost:80; }
```

Or, you could remove the dependency on bash by using named pipes:

```
mkfifo hostA.in hostA.out
socat - tcp:localhost:80 < hostA.in > hostA.out &
```

Comment: One of my goals with this project is to not fork out any external/3rd party apps, so the socat option is not appealing to me, but I really like your use of coprocs to work around the issue I was seeing.  I'll give that a shot!